# Camera overlay in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So without a screenshot you guys won't know *what* I'm talking about.. So here we go:

[image]

This particular part of my application I need to do an overlay over the camera interface as seen in the screenshot. 2 rectangles - And when you take the picture, I want to end up with 2 images, the cuttings taken from the 2 rectangles.

If this doesn't make sense, please comment and ask for clarification. I honestly don't even know where to begin with this one. What would be a good starting point? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to create your own Custom Camera:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

where you can implement your own preview layout - thus you can put those frames over camera preview as you wish

but it won't be easy as many of devices exists with many different camera resolutions, some work only in landscape, even though their native interface is portrait, it's a fake landscape; and also aligning those frames with the picture you'll be actually getting will be a challenge; but definitely this is Custom Camera - good luck